# node-sqlite3 running at end of TS

Tags: typescript, node-sqlite3

When querying a DB in TS using node-sqlite3 the query happens after everything else.

[The docs](https://github.com/TryGhost/node-sqlite3/wiki/API) haven't yielded any answers, though there may be something glaringly obvious that I've missed.

I've attempted both of the following

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose()
const dexDB = new sqlite3.Database('./sql/pokedexes.sqlite')
const monDB = new sqlite3.Database('./sql/mons.sqlite')

async function getDex(row: number): Promise<object>{
    dexDB.serialize(()=>{
        dexDB.get(`SELECT pokedex FROM pokedexes WHERE rowid = ${row}`, (err, row)=>{
            const dexObj = JSON.parse(row.pokedex)
            console.log(dexObj.pokeapiDexName)
            return dexObj         
        })
    })
}

const tempDex = await getDex(1)
console.log(tempDex.pokeapiDexName)

dexDB.close()
monDB.close()

export {}
```

```
function getDex(row: number): object{
    dexDB.serialize(()=>{
        dexDB.get(`SELECT pokedex FROM pokedexes WHERE rowid = ${row}`, (err, row)=>{
            const dexObj = JSON.parse(row.pokedex)
            console.log(dexObj.pokeapiDexName)
            return dexObj         
        })
    })
}

const tempDex = getDex(1)
console.log(tempDex.pokeapiDexName)

dexDB.close()
monDB.close()

export {}
```

both of which return the same output of

```
undefined
kanto
```

though I was expecting it to have output

```
kanto
kanto
```

In addition, I attempted to wrap the call in a Promise as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53822736/return-array-of-ids-from-sqlite3-database-using-node-sqlite3)

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose()
const dexDB = new sqlite3.Database('./sql/pokedexes.sqlite')
const monDB = new sqlite3.Database('./sql/mons.sqlite')

async function getDex(row: number): Promise<object>{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        let dexObj = {}
        dexDB.serialize(()=>{
            dexDB.get(`SELECT pokedex FROM pokedexes WHERE rowid = ${row}`, (err, row)=>{
                if(err){reject(err)}
                dexObj = JSON.parse(row.pokedex)
                console.log("inside func " + dexObj.pokeapiDexName);
                ()=>{resolve(dexObj)}
            })
        })
    })
}

console.log("before func call")
const tempDex = await getDex(1)
console.log("after func call")
console.log(tempDex)

dexDB.close()
monDB.close()

export {}
```

which returns

```
before func call
inside func kanto
```

as well as an indicator in vscode's terminal stating `Command executed now and failed (Exit Code 1)`

When I move `()=>{resolve(dexObj)}` outside as a tertiary parameter of `dexDB.get()` I no longer get `Command executed and failed`, though it returns to running the query at the end and outputs

```
before func call
after func call
{}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76447074/typescript-sqlite3-get-all-promise-resolve-list) provided a solution

`const dexDB = new sqlite3.Database('./sql/pokedexes.sqlite')`

must be called within the function itself, not at the beginning of the file.
Unsure as to why exactly, but it works now and properly outputs

```
before func call
after func call 
kanto
```